# Permalinks problem woocommerce no separating slash between categories

Tags: permalinks, woocommerce-offtopic

Im have and issue displaying the top level category and sub category within the permalink.

I can get the link to display both sub and parent cats however there is no separator between the cats. ie no backslash no hyphen.

this is what i have now.

mysite.co.uk/toys-and-hobbiesrc-toys-hobbiesrc-boat/feilun-ft011-65cm-2-4g-brushless-rc-boat-water-cooling-system/

as you can see above parent cat and sub cat are joined with no backslash

this should be

mysite.co.uk/toys-and-hobbies/rc-toys-hobbies/rc-boat/feilun-ft011-65cm-2-4g-brushless-rc-boat-water-cooling-system/

I would not even mind dropping the parent category from the url and just display the sub cats.

Just cant get it to work.

any ideas how to fix this would be appreciated.

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 1):

After messing around with the permalinks i have now found the cause of the problem. it was actually to do with with the categories themselves.  I uploaded via csv file however the categories even though separated by a forward slash in the csv only created parent categories, with really long names.

The solution was to delete the old names on the categories and then put them in order in under the settings / menu tab so that parents and child categories exist.

Was going to delete this. but i have been searching for an answer all night it was only after trying on a local server with new install that my situation was not standard.

I should have noticed sooner.

Hope this helps someone out there and saves you a bit of time